# Dual citizenship. Live 1m in Florida, 1m in Buenos Aires, 1 month in Florida, and so on. I'm covered in Argentina. What should I do while in the US?

Tags: united-states, health-insurance

Dual citizenship: American and Argentinian. I'm covered in Argentina, but does not have health insurance in the US. I would like a catastrophic plan, but they aren't offered to 46 years old. Do I have to go with super expensive ACA (i.e. Obamacare Market Place)?

Florida is quoting me $383 / month with a $8700 deductible and out-of-pocket. That's $4596 / year to only use the medical system in case of an emergency. Not to say that I'll only be in the country for 6 months every year, on average. It sounds like a rip-off / bad insurance, like a $1000 / month insurance in case a meteor hit the Earth. Do I have any other options? Non-ACA (heard they simply deny emergency claims and leave you with a bill)? Cancel and re-apply every other month? Pause it? I'm a good citizen and my finances are in the US. Don't want to risk them in case I need an appendectomy ($10,000-$35,000) or knock-on-wood I'm in a car accident.

I'm 46, separated, non pre-conditions, no health problems, no tobacco, etc.

Comment: Why do you consider ACA to be super-expensive? If it's cheaper than the other plans isn't it super-cheap?

Comment: If you made yourself resident in Argentina could you get annual travel insurance that covered six one-month visits to the US?